Mitigating vulnerability in runtime libraries
We run dotnet list <Solution>.sln package --vulnerable --include-transitive --source https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json nightly on our CI server to check wether we have a dependency on any vulnerable packages.
As of last tuesday, this fails due to CVE-2024-30105 and CVE-2024-38095.
Both of the vulnerable libraries (System.Text.Json and System.Formats.Asn1) are runtime libraries so we dont explicitly reference them as a Nuget Package. In fact we don't even use System.Formats.Asn1 at all (its usage appears to be transitive via Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Xml)
I was under the impression that all we had to do was to update the runtime on our CI server and instruct our customer to do the same on their machines.
So we did the former but we still get
Project `------------------` has the following vulnerable packages
   [net8.0]:
   Transitive Package         Resolved   Severity   Advisory URL
   > System.Formats.Asn1      8.0.0      High       https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-447r-wph3-92pm

Why is it still resolving to 8.0.0 when dotnet --version gives me 8.0.303 which according to The release notes for 8.0.7 (sdk 8.0.303)
includes fixes for both vulnerabilities?
What am I doing wrong? What am i (still :'( ) not understanding about .NET dependencies??!
Side note, we do use a global.json but with rollForward set to latestMinor
Maybe this is just a tooling issue: Possibly related Issue on GitHub?

what .net sdks are installed on your CI?

what is in your csproj?

dotnet --list-sdks outputs:
1.1.14, 2.1.202, 2.1.526, 2.2.110, 2.2.207, 3.1.302, 5.0.201, 5.0.401, 5.0.416, 6.0.201, 6.0.306, 7.0.101, 7.0.400, 8.0.100, 8.0.303

What part of the csproj?  It's a large solution with multiple projects. some of their properties are managed in a common Directory.build.props. Package versions are managed centrally in a Directory.packages.props. The latter does not explicitly reference neither System.Text.Json nor System.Formats.Asn1

Trying to explicitly add PackageVersion entries to Directory.packages.props for System.Text.Json and System.Formats.Asn1 in versions 8.0.4 and 8.0.1 respectively did absolutely nothing to fix the output from dotnet list :(

I think you are tricked by the fact that 8.0.0 here isn't the .net SDK version. Ie. it isn't supposed to be 8.0.303.
If you haven't already, take a look here: https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Formats.Asn1/8.0.1
To mitigate this you could add the package dependency explicitly. I would also add a comment explaining why it is there, as a reminder to remove it when possible.
<!-- System.Formats.Asn1 is added to mitigate vulnerability. -->
<!-- Remove as soon as Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer no longer depends on vulnerable version -->
<PackageReference Include="System.Formats.Asn1" Version="8.0.1" />


I was expecting it to resolve to 8.0.1. Thanks for the link to the patched version on nuget. I was hoping i could avoid adding the explicit reference. But it looks like that's the only option for now. I'll wait a little to see if there's any other ideas/hints or at least explanations out there before i'll mark this as an answer :)

It seems the behavior (not using the latest available patch) is by design (preventing supply chain attachs.. see discussion here: https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/11786) so there's no way around adding the explicit reference until Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Xml releases a patch that references System.Formats.Asn1 8.0.1. Bummer.

An alternative might be to use Paket.
From their FAQ: "Paket tries to embrace semantic versioning while NuGet uses a pessimistic version resolution strategy." This should give you more up-to-date transitive package versions and the lock file should prevent unwanted updates.
There also seem to be Plugins for VisualStudio and VSCode.

I have a similar issue now with the System.Text.Json package version, the newer vulnerability CVE-2024-43485, requiring package version 8.0.5 to fix.
Should this package version not be solely determined by the dotnet runtime?
When I search the \bin directories of an app or unit test project (not just library), no System.Text.Json.dll shows up, although many other System./Microsoft. DLLs are there.
I have SDK 8.0.403, runtime versions 8.0.10, where the issue shall be fixed, but the dotnet list command still shows vulnerable package version 8.0.4, instead of fixed 8.0.5.
Yes, I can update the existing "guard version" in Directory.Packages.props, but it shouldn't have any effect, especially in "final" code, which only goes into app/service/unit test. Or will it block execution on an older runtime?
Even where Microsoft itself uses those libraries, any version setting should be irrelevant, as long as runtime libraries are used and no specific package/DLL is delivered with them, to override the runtime version.
BTW: I found DLLs of System.Text.Json in NET 6 builds, although it has been part of the runtime since some 3.x version. => probably because the package was 8.0.x, while the project still targeted NET 6.

I solved the issue by adding a global.json file and specifying rollForward to use latestMinor. Then I updated the top-level packages and the warning has gone away.
